# Simplification with exponents

Tags: calculus, exponentiation, coding-theory

I'm currently revising an exam about channel coding in telecommunications and we have a question where we need to isolate a variable $u$ in terms of another variable $q$. Currently, I am stuck with a rather difficult expression to simplify or at least I can't see what the trick is (if there is one). Here is the said expression:

$$log_2\big(q^q(1-q)^{1-q}\big) = log_2\bigg((\frac{qu}{1-qu})^q\bigg)$$

Being perfectly honest, I know that the $log_2$ simplifies on each side but having $u$ in both the numerator and denominator of the fraction which has an overall exponent, I'm quite out of my comfort zone mathematically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $u$? It doesn't appear in the left hand side

Comment: That was one of my problems ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have on both sides the base $2$ we get
$$q^q(1-q)^{1-q}=\left(\frac {qu}{1-qu}\right)^q$$ Let's say $$A=q^q(1-q)^{1-q}$$ then $$a^{1/q}=\frac{qu}{1-qu}$$ so $$A^{1/q}-qA^{1/q}=qu$$ and $$A^{1/q}-quA^{1/q}=qu$$ so $$A^{1/q}=u(q+qA^{1/q})$$ and we obtain
$$u=\frac{A^{1/q}}{q+qA^{1/q}}$$